# Share openVPN connection

Tags: vpn, connection, share

Currently I have a server (dev tun) running openVPN and my WinXP client is able to connect to the server just fine.
I have an ethernet device and I need to send data to a computer under the server's network, so since the device can't connect on its own I need to configurate my Windows XP to share its VPN connection.

So, on my WinXP machine i have:

Network Adapter #1 (ip 192.168.0.2 gw 192.168.0.1 with internet access).

OpenVPN Connection (dhcp).

Network Adapter #2 (crossover cable with device).

Here is my client.ovpn

> cert gertec.crt
>
> key gertec.key
>
> client
>
> ns-cert-type server
>
> user nobody
>
> group nobody
>
> remote IP PORT
>
> ca ca.crt
>
> dev tun
>
> dev-node OpenVPN
>
> proto udp
>
> resolv-retry infinite
>
> nobind
>
> comp-lzo
>
> verb 3

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Windows XP was not meant for routing. However I think that you will have success with Internet Connection Sharing.

Comment: ICS will be hard, since (as far as I know) it's hardcoded to 192.168.0.0/24 and might conflict with the existing gateway. (Strangely, Windows can route IPv6 perfectly.)

Answer (score 1):

I used to share an OpenVPN link by setting it up in a Linux virtual machine`*`, and adding a route on the default gateway to that virtual machine (using RIP for fun, but can be easily done manually).

---

`*` *I found coLinux to be very lightweight.*